# How Can I Speed This Up? Updated Code Better but Not Good Enough

Tags: vb.net

The code below works perfectly for small directories, but when I try it on a larger one (only 8,500 files) it takes about an hour. All it's doing is copying files listed in a dictionary from one directory to another. It's the `bgworker_DoWork()` method that is taking the time. It populates the dictionary in a second or two, but then the grinding begins. I've even tried commenting out the update progress code to see if that helps - it didn't.

One thing I noticed: when I had the progress indicator on the first 10% of files finished pretty quickly, but they each slowed more after that. I'd appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

    'Set the count to 30
    m_CountTo = intLVIndex - 1
    ' Disable the start button
    Me.StartButton.Enabled = False
    ' Enable to stop button
    Me.StopButton.Enabled = True
    ' Start the Background Worker working

    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_CountTo
        dict.Add(Me.LVFiles.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text,
                Me.LVFiles.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
    Next

    LabelTask.Visible = True
    LabelTask.Text = "Copying"
    LabelStatus.Visible = True
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(dict)

End Sub

Private Sub StopButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
    ' Is the Background Worker do some work?
    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        'If it supports cancellation, Cancel It
        If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
            ' Tell the Background Worker to stop working.
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End If
    ' Enable to Start Button
    Me.StartButton.Enabled = True
    ' Disable to Stop Button
    Me.StopButton.Enabled = False


End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim counter As Integer = -1
    Dim prgctr As Integer = 0

    For Each kvp In DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        counter += 1

        ' Has the background worker been told to stop?
        If Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            ' Set cancel to True
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        strSourceFilePath = kvp.Key
        strDestFilePath = kvp.Value

        ' Do the file copy here
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strSourceFilePath, strDestFilePath, overwrite:=False)

        'If prgctr = 50 Then
        '    'Report the progress of the background worker
        '    Me.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt((counter / m_CountTo) * 100), counter)
        '    prgctr = 0
        'Else
        '    prgctr += 1
        'End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ' Update the progress bar
    'Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    'Me.LVFiles.Items(Convert.ToInt32(e.UserState)).Selected = True
    'Me.LabelStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString & "%"
End Sub

Private Sub My_BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        Me.LabelStatus.Text = "Cancelled"
    Else
        Me.LabelStatus.Text = "Completed"
    End If
End Sub

' The delegate
Delegate Sub SetLabelText_Delegate(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)

' The delegates subroutine.
Private Sub SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    If [Label].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New SetLabelText_Delegate(AddressOf SetLabelText_ThreadSafe)
        Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[Label], [text]})
    Else
        [Label].Text = [text]
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this: `DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String)` from the loop initialization and assign the result of the cast to a local variable. The code you posted is probably incomplete: `strSourceFilePath` and `strDestFilePath` are not declared here (as they should) and neither of these is required; it's not clear how `SetLabelText_ThreadSafe` is involved (or what you tried to do with it), since you (fortunately) never use it in this code; but, then, why posting it here? Are you actually using that code somehow?

Comment: @Jimi - In my original code I was retrieving data from a ListView on the UI side but was getting cross-threading errors. It was suggested that I use a dictionary to retrieve the data from the LV before I start the loop and that's what I'm doing. (Populating the dictionary is pretty much instantaneous. strSourceFilePath and strDestFilePath are definitely required as they're parameters for the CopyFile. As you suspected, they are populated earlier in the code. The ThreadSafe is used to populate the progress information on the UI. It's commented out now only to see if that speeds things up. Nope